# How to send Push notifications - Google Assistant

Tags: firebase, push-notification, actions-on-google, google-home, dialogflow-es

```js
   # index.js

const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const DialogflowApp = require('actions-on-google').DialogflowApp;

exports.handler = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {

    const app = new DialogflowApp({ request: req, response: res });
    console.log("Request", req);

    console.log('Request Processing ');
    function responseHandler(app) {
        let intent = app.getIntent();
        console.log("INFO Intent : ", intent);
        switch (intent) {
            case 'input.welcome':
                console.log("INFO : UserId: ", app.getUser().userId);
                app.ask("Welcome  to notify Applcation")
                break;

            case 'finish_permission':
                if (app.isPermissionGranted()) {
                    console.log("INFO : UserId: ", app.getUser().userId);
                    app.ask("Ok, I'll start alerting you");
                } else {
                    app.ask("Ok, I won't alert you");
                }
                break;

            case 'check_overdue_tasks':
                if (app.isPermissionGranted()) {
                    console.log("INFO : UserId: ", app.getUser().userId);
                    app.ask("Ok, I'll start alerting you");
                } else {
                    app.ask("Ok, I won't alert you");
                }
                break;


            case 'setup_update':
                app.askForUpdatePermission('check_overdue_tasks');
                break;
        }
    }
    app.handleRequest(responseHandler);

})


################################################## send ##############################################


var request = require('request')
const google = require('googleapis');
const key = require('../config/Agent33-e4a3b7e88308.json');


let notif = {
    userNotification: {
        title: 'Pay Parking tickets',
    },
    target: {
        userId: 'ABwppHF74yXbA9Z1ptgyOVwwkU8p9meRgs3H51Aw6_AqQZTzUgFzdz1twy6ki1aI-CjziWJPlqSdJUdbzQ',
        intent: 'check_overdue_tasks'
    }
}


let jwtClient = new google.auth.JWT(
    key.client_email, null, key.private_key,
    ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/actions.fulfillment.conversation'],
    null
);

jwtClient.authorize(function (err, tokens) {
    if (err) {
        console.log("ERROR on jwt CLIENT");
    }
    else {
        console.log("Token : ", JSON.stringify(tokens) + "\n Notification Msg : " + JSON.stringify(notif));

        request.post('https://actions.googleapis.com/v2/conversations:send', {
            'auth': {
                'bearer': tokens.access_token
            },
            'json': true,
            'body': { 'customPushMessage': notif, 'isInSandbox': true }
        }, function (err, httpResponse, body) {
            console.log(httpResponse.statusCode + ': ' + httpResponse.statusMessage)
        });
    }
});


############################################################################################
```

I exactly followed the steps illustrated in documentation :

https://developers.google.com/actions/assistant/updates

The issues encountered are :

ISSUE 1 :

app.askForUpdatePermission(INTENT) :  is not updating the permission to send push notification for the intent but it says the permission is granted. 
and in case tried to execute the 'final_permission' intent again, its say the permission is granted .

As when I try to execute 
app.isPermissionGranted() , it returned false.

ISSUE 2 : The Server 'https://actions.googleapis.com/v2/conversations:send' returned 500 or 400 Error randomly.

I am using free plan of FireBase (Spark) Is it because of that ?

Comment: If you can show the code you used to do both, we can probably help you better.

Comment: Thanks , i added the code

Comment: If you're using Firebase you need to setup billing to make outbound network calls but the googleapis.com domain should work without needing billing because its inside Google's network

Comment: okay let me check , thanks

Comment: Even i checked again I couldn't find any issue , why the server is returning 500 or 400 error

Comment: Did you succeed ? In my case after : app.askForUpdatePermission('check_overdue_tasks'); the simulator is returning 'Sorry, I didn't get any response' . Any idea ? should we use API V2 for notification ?

Comment: No, maybe its because of beta version. the issues still persist.

Comment: Test it on a real device. You will get notification. Make sure you have done proper setup as per (https://developers.google.com/actions/assistant/updates) link.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have set exact `intentname` like `setup_update` and text should be exact for `Suggestion chips.` Otherwise your assistant won't recognize text.

Make sure you have enable webhook for specific intent if you had handle using code.

Hope you read and follow their [Action On Google](https://developers.google.com/actions/assistant/updates) document.

Test it on a real device. You will get a notification.